# How to tell a client that a file doesn't exist in the server in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm writing a simple client-server simple application, in which the client requests a certain file to the server. If the file exists, the server sends the file and its size; if it doesn't exists, then the server sends a message to the client saying the file couldn't be found. I included the exception in the server, but I don't know how to include the if clause in the client: if the file exists, the receive the file; else, receive the message saying it doesn't exist. I think I managed to do this on the server side, but I'm not really sure of how may I write this code to only print the message "file not found" in the client if the file wasn't found in the server

Here's the server side code

```
import socket
import os
import sys
import pickle

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8881

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    print("Server", host, "waiting on port", port)
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connected to: " + str(addr))
        filename = ''
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            filename += data
        print("File requested: " + filename)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            lista = []
            myfile = os.path.getsize(filename)
            size = ('File size: ',myfile,' bytes')
            texto = ''
            for i in size:
                texto = texto + '{:>4}'.format(i)
            print(texto)
            lista.append(texto)
            file_size = pickle.dumps(lista)
            c.send(file_size)
            file2send = open(filename, "rb")
            c.send(file2send.read())
            c.close()
        else:
            print("File not found")
            msg = ('File not found')
            s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And the client side:

```
import socket, os.path, datetime, sys, pickle

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8881

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    Filename = input("File name and extension: ")
    s.send(Filename.encode('utf-8'))
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    file_size = s.recv(1024)
    lista = pickle.loads(file_size)
    print(lista)
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print(data)
    msg = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print(msg)
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: When you receive the `data`, check if it is `"File not found"`. However, your program fails if the contents of the requested file is literally `File not found`. You should first send the status and only then, if the status is Ok, send the file contents.

Comment: I tried doing this, but somehow the program fails, because it just ignores the if clause containing the condition to check if the file exists, and then goes on, but crashes because the file doesn't exist, so the program just breaks the connection

Comment: So, you did not write your question correctly. Your problem is very different from what you tell us. If you ask a wrong question, how do you expect to get a right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server, you are sending "file not found" message to server socket `s`, instead you should send that to client `c` and as per your logic you should send message length first and then message before closing the connection.
Please refer below server code.

**Server:**

```py
import socket
import os
import sys
import pickle

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8881

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    print("Server", host, "waiting on port", port)
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connected to: " + str(addr))
        filename = ''
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            filename += data
        print("File requested: " + filename)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            lista = []
            myfile = os.path.getsize(filename)
            size = ('File size: ',myfile,' bytes')
            texto = ''
            for i in size:
                texto = texto + '{:>4}'.format(i)
            print(texto)
            lista.append(texto)
            file_size = pickle.dumps(lista)
            c.send(file_size)
            file2send = open(filename, "rb")
            c.send(file2send.read())
            c.close()
        else:
            print("File not found")
            msg = ('File not found')
            c.send(str(len(msg)).encode('utf-8'))
            c.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
            c.close()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: @HStoltz, did this answer your question?

Comment: Not really, I think the problem is in the client. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this correctly enough (oh dear, being a beginner is hard to the beginner and to everyone who tries to help haha), but want to make a condition in the client to only receive the message if the file wasn't found in the server

Comment: As of now, in your code you are not making any distinction between file and message, if you want to (like, write in a file, if file content received, or just display otherwise), you have to send the message accordingly. For example, send message type as well, along with file size like `size=20,type=message` or `size=340,type=file`, so that your client can decide, what to do with incoming content.